Having a problem trying to get the correct information displayed on multiple records after changing them
I have a change record function the only problem is that it only lets me change the first record which is record 0, but when I try to change record 1 and display it comes out with an error.
I am expecting to be able to able to change multiple records and display them correctly
int changeRecord() {
    int recordNum;
    InventoryItem item;

    ofstream newFile("file.dat", ios::trunc);  // Open file in append mode 
    if (!newFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening the file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Enter the record number: ";
    cin >> recordNum;
    if (recordNum < 1)
        recordNum = 1;
    recordNum--;
    cout << "Please enter the item description: ";
    cin.ignore();  // To avoid issues with leftover newline characters
    cin.getline(item.itemDescription, DESC_SIZE);
    cout << "Please enter the total amount of this item on hand: ";
    cin >> item.quantityOnHand;

    cout << "Please enter the wholesale cost of the item: ";
    cin >> item.wholesaleCost;

    cout << "Please enter the retail cost of the item: ";
    cin >> item.retailCost;

    cout << "Please enter the date this item was added to the inventory (YYYY-MM-DD): ";
    cin.ignore();  // Ignore newline left in the input buffer 
    cin.getline(item.dateAddedToInventory, DATE_SIZE);

    newFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&item), sizeof(item));  // Write the item to file  
    newFile.close();
    return 0;
}


ofstream newFile("file.dat", ios::trunc);  // Open file in append mode The comment doesn't match the code. You are not in fact opening the file in append mode. trunc is for "truncate", meaning, all existing content in the file (if any) is discarded, and the file starts with length zero.

So you get the user to provide recordNum, but you aren't actually using the provided value for anything. How did you mean to use it?
